# Dynamically adding data to select using jQuery chosen plugin

Tags: jquery-chosen

I am facing a problem of dynamically adding options to multiple select using chosen plugin.

As I have millions of records in database so I can not populate all as options during page load.

so now I have to get matching records (on keyup event) from database using ajax and populate select box dynamically. is there any way i can achieve this.

Comment: Simply adding `option`s to the `select` won't do?

Comment: no i am using chosen plugin,once i add options on click and call     $("#form_field").trigger("liszt:updated"); earlier entries disappearing :(

Answer (score 2):

You can just select the option you want manually by value as such:

```
$("#form_field").val('value_to_be_selected');
```

and then call

`$("#form_field").trigger("liszt:updated");`

Comment: thanks gal, but its not working for me, i have to refresh my select onKeyUp and as soon as i refresh previous chars of textbox are gone :(

Comment: OK, If you're using a multiple select then the value returned from val() is an array. you can try to retrieve the array using $("#form_field").val(), push the new item to the array, and then  reassign the array using $("#form_field").val(new_array)

Comment: You can actually do this with one line `$("#form_field").val('value_to_be_selected').trigger("liszt:updated");`.

Answer (score 0):

We can easily append option to chosen by using the following option.

```
<select class=”chosen-select”>
<option value=”101”>Hyderabad</option>
<option value=”102”>Banglore</option>
<option value=”103”>Chennai</option>
</select>

$(".chosen-select").append('<option value="104”>Delhi</option>');
$(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

For more information related to chosen jquery dropdown you can click here  http://www.dotnetqueries.com/Article/151/how-to-implement-chosen-plugin-with-example